# function distance time word problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A tourist walks n km at 4 km/h, then travels 2n km at 36 km/h by bus.  Express the total traveling time t (in hours) as a function of n.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Thanks NF Taussig.  I wasn't aware of that.  My approach was to use 4t to represent the walking portion, and 36t for the bus portion.  4 km/hr for the first leg, 18 km/hr for the second.  The velocity is 4.5 times greater for the second leg.  So, t(n) = n + 9n = 10n.  But I know the answer is 6n.  I don't know where I'm going off course here.

Comment: Hint...time = distance divided by speed

Answer (score 1):

Recall that speed= distance/time.

So, time=distance/speed.

Let $t_1$ be the time the journey on foot takes.
Let $t_2$ be the time the journey by bus takes.
Let $T$ be the total time.

Thus, we have $T = t_1 + t_2$.

For $t_1$:

$$t_1 = \frac{d}{s} = \frac{n}{4}$$

For $t_2$:

$$t_2 = \frac{d}{s} = \frac{2n}{36} = \frac{n}{18}$$

Thus, we have:

$$T = \frac{n}{4} + \frac{n}{18} = \frac{11n}{36}$$

Comment: Therefore, T(n)=11n/36

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, I would suggest using subscripts on $d$ and $s$ in your equations for $t_1$ and $t_2$.

Comment: Thanks Vabo, for your answer!  And thanks NFT for your recommendations on typesetting.  Will follow them.